# targeting select option from dropdown to hide or show buttons

Tags: jquery

I want to select an option, and based on that option show a button.

The code is below. I felt that it was right, but I guess not. Please help:

```
$('#flavorBlend, #twoBag, #shipInterval').hide();
    $('#cancelChoices').change(function() {
        if ('select option[value=003]') {
            $('#flavorBlend').show("fast");
            } else {
                $('#flavorBlend').hide();
            }
    });
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking if the string `'select option[value=003]'` is true. It always will be. So get the value of the drop down and compare it to a string. Try this if you use

```
<option>flavor</option>
```

in your `<select>`

```
$('#flavorBlend, #twoBag, #shipInterval').hide();
$('#cancelChoices').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "flavor") {
        $('#flavorBlend').show("fast");
    } else {
        $('#flavorBlend').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try that